# Find hash in interval

Tags: sha1

I have an SHA-224 hash and I know it can be made with a number from 0.0000(29 0s)1 and 0.999(30 9s). How could I check if a given hash is made with a number in some interval, I.e. between 0.00(29 0s) and 0.666(30 6s), without having to calculate all the hashes.

Comment: The point of cryptographic hashes is to allow as few predictions as possible about the original value from it's hash.

Comment: Is this question related to c++ or c# in any way?

Comment: I think you're missing the point of a hash.  Read up on what a [Cryptographic Hash Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) actually does.  Hint:  It only works in ONE direction, and therefore this cannot be done (without generating every hash)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do what you want to do with SHA-224 without calculating all of the hashes and building lookup tables.

Comment: Well I know that but I was thinking if there's another way. Apparently there isn't. Thank you :D